# html display:none is not wotking for mobile devices

Tags: html, mobile, eventbrite, displayobject

I am using the following html code to hide the registration buttons on www.eventbrite.com:

**

```
<style> 
#ticketInfo  {
    display: none !important;
}

#TicketReg  {display: none !important;
}

#see_whos_going .panel_head2 {
    margin-top: -27px;
}

#OrderReg  {display:none !important;}
</style>
```

This works fine on desktop, but does not seem to work on mobile devices e.g. iPhone. I am a coding novice, so any sugestions would be much appreciated!

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your html code as well, `display:none !important` works for both.

Comment: It's possible that you have errors in your HTML, which are handled differently by the iPhone browser than by other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile optimized view of the Eventbrite event pages don't render the HTML/CSS that are added to the custom header by the customer/event organizer (unlike the desktop version where you can essentially add your own CSS to overwrite any style element).